# android IOException EFAULT

Tags: java, android

I'm writing mp4parser movie to file and get this error :

> java.io.IOException: write failed: EFAULT (Bad address)

My code :

```
Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(video);

FileOutputStream fos;

try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    out.writeContainer(fos.getChannel());
    fos.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

All permissions are added in manifest.

Comment: What address are you providing to the code that throws the exception?